# How to make Coding Simple Request Form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, registration

Having to make a Request Form from scratch and a little on confused on what all i need to make it work. Here is the HTML I'm having to use and the javacode is what i've put together by scratch, its saying unexpected token } on line 18 in .js file but i need the } to complete the function.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Chapter 10: Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" placeholder="Name" /></td>
            <td><p class="error" id="txtNameError">Name must be at least 6 characters long.</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtPhone" id="txtPhone" placeholder="Phone: ###-###-####" /></td>
            <td><p class="error" id="txtPhoneError">Phone must be in the format ###-###-####.</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email Address" /></td>
            <td><p class="error" id="txtEmailError">Must be a valid email address.</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><button id="btnRegister" name="btnRegister">Register</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Chapter10.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Chapter10.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Code I've had to make so far,

```
function validateForm(){
var nameTxt = document.getElementById('txtName');
var phoneTxt = document.getElementById('txtPhone');
var emailTxt = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
{
if(allLetter(nameTxt))
{
if(ValidateEmail(txtEmail))
{
if(validatePhone(txtPhone))
}
}
return false;
console.log()
}
}
function allLetter(nameTxt) {

var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(nameTxt.value.match(letters))
{  
return true;  
}   
else  
{  
alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');  
nameTxt.focus();  
return false;  
}  
} 

function phoneNumber(txtPhone){
var phoneTxt = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
if (txtPhone.value.match(phoneTxt))
{
    return ture;
}
else {
    alert("Eneter Vaild Phone Number");
    return false;
}
}

function ValidateEmail(txtEmail){   

if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*  (\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.emailAddr.value))  
{  
return (true)  
}  
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")  
return (false)  
}  


function init(){
var btnRegister = document.getElementById('btnRegister');
btnRegister.onclick = btnRegister;
}
window.onload = init;
```

What is there left to add to make it working? I'm all out of idea's Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. since your code is not formatted you are lost in brackets in method
   `validateForm()`

update to this:

```
function validateForm(){
    var nameTxt = document.getElementById('txtName');
    var phoneTxt = document.getElementById('txtPhone');
    var emailTxt = document.getElementById('txtEmail');

    if(allLetter(nameTxt))
    {
        if(ValidateEmail(txtEmail))
        {
            if(validatePhone(txtPhone))
            {
            }
        }
    }
  console.log();
  return false;
}
```

2. update this method.

this

```
function init(){
    var btnRegister = document.getElementById('btnRegister');
  btnRegister.onclick = btnRegister;
}
```

to this

```
function init(){
    var btnReg = document.getElementById('btnRegister');
    btnReg.onclick = BtnRegister;
}
```

3. create method

```
function BtnRegister()
{
    alert("here i am.");
}
```

4. update

this

```
window.onload = init;
```

to this

```
window.onload = init();
```

5. i'm commented this `<script type="text/javascript" src="Chapter10.js"></script>` since i can't see what it contains.

Comment: I'm very new to this and its stressed me to the max, what do i need to edit so you can see the page?

Comment: i got the code formatted, and everything works like it should, but when i click register it says here i am, it should register the information i think.

Comment: it should not do anything while you are not coded what it should do. @J.Bush if question solved mark it so please.